# Impose linking to specific python library on OSX Lion

Tags: python, macos

I am building a python module from c++ files, using swig, and I also have a local build of python 2.7 in my home directory, on OSX 10.8. I want to build with my local python, but osx has a system python, and that causes some trouble. I get the following error

```
>>> import example
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

which according to browsing around, it's due to my python executing, but the module linking against the system python.

I deployed a small swig example, [as from tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html), and then linked as follows

```
gcc -shared -I builddir/include/python2.7/ example.c example_wrap.c \
     -o _example.so -L builddir/lib/python2.7/ -lpython2.7
```

Sure enough, the _example.so keeps binding against the system python, probably because frameworks come first in the resolution, although I am not sure if this is at linking time or at execution time.

```
_example.so:
    _example.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.2)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

how can I force it to bind against my own python library?

**Edit**: I successfully managed to make it import by doing a

```
 install_name_tool -change 
       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       @executable_path/../lib/libpython2.7.dylib
```

but it feels like a hack. Can't I just let the linker find the library for me and put the appropriate reference in it? Can't I just specify the library name (libpython2.7.dylib) and let it resolve at runtime as it happens in Linux ?

Comment: Since there's no ldconfig equivelent for dyld (or ability to add arbitrary new paths system wide for dyld to 'pick up' new libraries - I'm betting the install_name_tool thing is probably the closest you'll get to a solution that doesn't involve (1) installing to system library paths (/lib,/usr/lib), or DYLD_* environment variables. Another solution would be to link to a static Python lib (.a)

Comment: recently had same problem with a simple cython extension in virtualenv, it used to work before (osx 10.7), not sure what changed, thus would like to know the authoritative answer. P.S. I've seen a hack solution where the target `.dylib` was renamed just so that the right version could be linked to...

Comment: I was going to suggest attempting this inside a virtualenv, but it's interesting that @qarma is having a similar issue there.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to test the solution, because I don't have tan OSX machine to test it here, but I think this can solve your problem:

Create a (or edit one) run script and change your alias or your PATH variable:

```
alias python='/your/local/python'
PATH=/your/local/python:$PATH

# Run your app here
```

Let me know if this helps.